In Hibernate 5, The Jsonb sql column Serializer/Deserializer using SnakeCase than the camelCase (TypeDef JsonBinaryType)
While saving/retrieving Jsonb Object in a DB. JSON key are saved in SnakeCase than the CamelCase
Entity Class
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Message {
  ...
  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(name = "message", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  com.example.vo.CompanyDetailsDTO companyDetails;
  ...
}

CompanyDetailsDTO.java
public class CompanyDetailsDTO {
  String companyName;
  Address companyAddress;
  ....
}

Currently its saved/retrieved as
{ "company_name" : "abc", "company_address" : { ... } }


I tried to create my own JsonBinaryType by extending it, however i am failed to set the objectMapper property
Even tried to use the CustomeConvertor extending AttributeConverter<CompanyDetailsDTO, String>
both the methods dint work

Ideally i am expecting to be saved as
{ "companyName" : "abc", "companyAddress" : { ... } }

By any way can i change the Serialize/Deserialize based on camelCase of the property than the snakeCase
